# Acer G9-793 shows two 120GB M.2 SSDs, not one 240GB SSD. Why?

Tags: partition, system-installation, ssd, laptop, acer

I am trying to install POP! OS to my Acer Predator 17 (G9-793). When going to partition my C drive, i noticed that my 240 GB C drive was showing up as two 120 GB drives and were unallocated. I had to create a new partition table; gparted had an error when I tried fo format. This was at the end of the log:

> set partition type on /dev/sda1  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )
>
> new partition type: ext4
>
> create new ext4 file system  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
>
> mkfs.ext4 -F -O ^64bit -L '' '/dev/sda1'  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
>
> mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
>   /dev/sda1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!

How do I set this up?

Comment: Do you want to dual-boot with Windows or have only Pop_OS? For standalone you can right away change the SATA mode, in UEFI, to AHCI (it's probably as "RAID" now). Then disable CSM  or make sure you're booting in UEFI mode. Maybe additional steps are necessary.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I would just like Pop. I'll try to figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Acer's comments site](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/541317/acer-predator-17-g9-793-79v5-m2-ssd-type), you really don't have 240GB. You have a pair of M.2 120GB SSDs. You can create volumes on each, then join them together with LVM, and make an ext4 partition [following this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219881/how-can-i-create-one-logical-volume-over-two-disks-using-lvm); or, you can use one for /root and one for /home .

Comment: Ok, how should I go about installing POP?

Comment: @TannerJames Start by my comment above ;)

Comment: First you must decide if you want to have one 240GB volume by the use of LVM, or two 120GB drives (with root on one and /home on the other),